# Japanese dictionary for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to see what dictionaries are currently configured for an installed version of Postgresql? I looked into tsearch_data folder and saw the stop words files. Is there a 1:1 relationship between a stop words file and a dictionary?

In case there isn't any japanese dictionary available, can it be imported from external resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Laszlo from the Hunspell project, I found a japanese dictionary in here http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/i18npool/source/breakiterator/data/ja.dic

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from pg_ts_dict;
```

should show you all installed dictionaries.

Postgres can use [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) dictionaries and I have succesfully used the ones from the OpenOffice project. But as far as I can tell there is no Japanese directory for OpenOffice.

But maybe there is a Japanese hunspell dictionary from other projects.

Comment: There's no such table as pg_dict in my posgtresql distribution, there's something called pg_ts_dict on pg_catalog, don't know if the two are supposed to show the same data. Thanks for pointing me to the OpenOffice project, and you were right, there is no japanese dictionary in there.

Comment: @ht0ma: you are right the name is 'pg_ts_dict', sorry. I was typing from memory.